# Attempting to compare values in two different Data Extensions using an inner and outer for loop

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions

I'm still attempting to grasp AMP script and all of it's functionality. In this instance, i'm using an outer for loop to loop through one DE and grab that information.

The inner for loop is used to gain further information from another table.

What I want to do, is IF someone has multiple (example) planes on the first table, I want to display those planes alongside with any relevant information pulled from my other table.

Example Code below:

```
        <!--Code to grab plane information from dataExtensionOne-->
        %%[

        SET @dataExtensionOne = LookupOrderedRows('pilot_planes', 0, 'pilot_plane_id DESC', 'pilot_id', _subscriberkey)
        SET @totalPlanes = RowCount(@dataExtensionOne)

                FOR @i = 1 to @totalPlanes DO
                SET @make = Field(Row(@dataExtensionOne,@i),'make')
                SET @model = Field(Row(@dataExtensionOne,@i),'model')
                SET @year = Field(Row(@dataExtensionOne,@i),'year')
                SET @status = Field(Row(@dataExtensionOne,@i),'status')
                SET @pilot_plane_id = Field(Row(@dataExtensionOne,@i),'pilot_plane_id')
        ]%%



        <!--We only want to see planes that have a status of approved or new.-->
        %%[IF @status == 'new' OR @status == 'approved' THEN]%%




        <!--Code to grab information from dataExtensionTwo-->
        %%[

        SET @dataExtensionTwo = LookupOrderedRows('pilot_planes_information', 0, 'pilot_plane_id DESC', 'pilot_id', _subscriberkey)
        SET @totalPlaneDocuments = RowCount(@dataExtensionTwo)
        SET @found_result = False
                FOR @j = 1 TO @totalPlaneDocuments DO
                    if not @found_result then

                SET @planeMake = Field(Row(@dataExtensionTwo,@j),'make')
                SET @planeModel = Field(Row(@dataExtensionTwo,@j),'model')
                SET @planeYear = Field(Row(@dataExtensionTwo,@j),'year')
                SET @multiple_document_type = FIELD(Row(@dataExtensionTwo,@j),'document_type')
                SET @multiple_display_name = FIELD(Row(@dataExtensionTwo,@j),'display_name')
                SET @multiple_expiration_date = FIELD(Row(@dataExtensionTwo,@j),'expires_at')
                SET @multiple_pilot_plane_id = FIELD(Row(@dataExtensionTwo,@j),'pilot_plane_id')
        ]%%

            %%[IF @planeMake == @make AND @planeModel == @model AND @planeYear == @year THEN
                  SET @found_result = True
            ]%%

                    %%=v(@make)=%% %%=v(@model)=%% %%=v(@year)=%%

                    %%=v(@multiple_document_type)=%% %%=FORMAT(@multiple_expiration_date, "MMM d")=%%


        %%[ENDIF]%%
        %%[endif]%% 
        %%[next @j]%%

        %%[ENDIF]%%
        %%[next @i]%%
```

So, for example, let's say in dataExtension one, I have:

```
make   | model | year 
plane A| alpha | 2010
plane B| beta  | 2007
```

and in dataExtension two, I have:

```
make    | model | year | document_type | expires_at
plane A | alpha | 2010 | document A    | Feb, 2018
plane A | alpha | 2010 | document B    | Mar, 2018
```

I want to display:

```
Plane Information: plane A Alpha 2010

Expiring Information: documentA Feb, 2018
document B Mar, 2018
```

Any information or help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your second lookup needs to use resulting field values from the first.  I'd also simplify it like this:

```
%%[

SET @planes = LookupOrderedRows('pilot_planes', 0, 'pilot_plane_id DESC', 'pilot_id', _subscriberkey)
SET @totalPlanes = RowCount(@planes)

FOR @i = 1 to @totalPlanes DO

    set @row1 = Row(@planes,@i)
    SET @make = Field(@row1,'make')
    SET @model = Field(@row1,'model')
    SET @year = Field(R@row1,'year')
    SET @status = Field(@row1,'status')
    SET @pilot_plane_id = Field(@row1,'pilot_plane_id')

    output(concat("<br>", @make," ", @model, " ", @year))

    IF @status == 'new' OR @status == 'approved' THEN

            SET @planeInfo = LookupRows('pilot_planes_information', @make, "model", @model, "year", @year)
            SET @totalPlaneDocuments = RowCount(@planeInfo)

            FOR @j = 1 TO @totalPlaneDocuments DO

              set @row2 = Row(@planeInfo, @j)  

              SET @document_type = FIELD(@row2,'document_type')
              SET @display_name = FIELD(@row2,'display_name')
              SET @expiration_date = FIELD(@row2,'expires_at')

              output(concat("<br>", @document_type," ", format(@expiration_date, "MMM d")))

            next @j
    ENDIF

next @i

]%%
```